# jquery select tbody with attr value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given a table

```
<table id="t1" class="dataList dataTable">
  <thead><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td><td>c</td></tr></thead>
  <tbody role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</tfoot>
```

How can I select the `<tr>` of the `<tbody>` with role="alert"?

The reason is I would like to do something to these selection. With jquery.datatables plugin, those tr are varies depends on "dataTables_length" selection. In other words, if with the plugin installed, Only those visible rows would be selected.

TIA.

Comment: Thanks for acceptance, plz also vote up for the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#t1 > tbody[role="alert"] tr')
```

which selects tbody elements with role='alert' that are the direct descendant of #t1.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
$('tbody[role="alert"] tr', '#t1');
```

which finds all tbody elements with role='alert' within the context of #t1.

Comment: The space is not a direct descendant selector. That would be `>`. Your first selector selects `tr` elements, which is what the question is asking, and your second selector selects the `tbody` element, which is *not* what the question is asking.

Answer (score 2):

try with

```
$('tbody[role="alert"] tr')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('table#t1>tbody[role="alert"] tr').css('background-color','#ddd');
```